# Jwt claim contains and needs user's id to generate token but how to know user's id before logging in?

Tags: rust, jwt

I am making web app using `Rust` using `Rocket` and `Diesel` for backend and `Yew` for frontend.

I am stuck and don't know how to proceed.

I have this function in the backend,

```rust
    pub fn login(conn: &mut PgConnection, user: LoginUser) -> QueryResult<ResponseUser> {
        match verify_user_credentials(conn, user.username.as_str(), user.password.as_str()) {
            Ok(Some(user)) => user,
            Ok(None) => {
                return Err(diesel::result::Error::NotFound);
            }
            Err(_) => {
                return Err(diesel::result::Error::NotFound);
            }
        };

        let secret = env::var("JWT_SECRET").expect("JWT_SECRET must be set.");
        let jwt_token = match encode_token(secret, user.id) {    // <-----
            Ok(token) => token,
            Err(_) => return Err(diesel::result::Error::NotFound),
        };

        let updated_user = diesel::update(users::table.filter(users::username.eq(user.username)))
            .set(users::token.eq(jwt_token))
            .returning(ResponseUser::as_returning())
            .get_result(conn)?;

        Ok(updated_user)
    }
```

the related model for the above function,

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct LoginUser {
    // pub id: i32,
    pub username: String,
    pub email: String,
    pub password: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Queryable, Selectable)]
#[diesel(table_name = users)]
#[diesel(check_for_backend(diesel::pg::Pg))]
pub struct ResponseUser {
    pub id: i32,
    pub username: String,
    pub email: String,
    pub token: Option<String>,
}
```

here is the `verify_user_credentials()`,

```rust
pub fn verify_user_credentials(
    conn: &mut PgConnection,
    username: &str,
    password: &str,
) -> Result<Option<User>, AuthenticationError> {
    // Fetch user data from the database
    let user_data = users::table
        .filter(users::username.eq(username))
        .select((
            users::id,
            users::username,
            users::email,
            users::token,
            users::hashed_password,
            users::last_login,
            users::created_at,
        ))
        .first::<User>(conn)
        .optional()
        .map_err(AuthenticationError::DatabaseError)?;

    if let Some(user) = user_data {
        let parsed_hash = PasswordHash::new(&user.hashed_password)?;

        assert!(Argon2::default()
            .verify_password(password.as_bytes(), &parsed_hash)
            .is_ok());

        let argon2 = Argon2::default();

        // Verify password using Argon2
        match argon2.verify_password(password.as_bytes(), &parsed_hash) {
            Ok(_) => Ok(Some(user)),
            Err(e) => {
                if e == password_hash::Error::Password {
                    Err(AuthenticationError::IncorrectPassword)
                } else {
                    Err(AuthenticationError::Argon2Error(e))
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        Ok(None)
    }
}
```

and the appropriate route for this function (in the backend),

```rust
#[post("/users/login", format = "json", data = "<login_user>")]
pub async fn login_user(
    db_pool: DbConnectionPool,
    login_user: Json<LoginUser>,
) -> Result<Value, status::Custom<Value>> {
    db_pool
        .run(|c| {
            Query::login(c, login_user.into_inner())
                .map(|user| json!(user))
                .map_err(|e| match e {
                    Error::NotFound => status::Custom(http::Status::NotFound, json!(e.to_string())),
                    _ => status::Custom(http::Status::InternalServerError, json!(e.to_string())),
                })
        })
        .await
}
```

as you can see in this line,

```rust
        let jwt_token = match encode_token(secret, user.id) {
```

I use `user.id` which I don't know how could I know before logging in. But it is need (as of now) to encode a new token for the user.

Here is the `Claims` `struct` and `encode_token()`,

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Claims {
    pub id: i32,
    pub exp: usize,
}

pub fn encode_token(secret: String, id: i32) -> Result<String, AuthenticationError> {
    let exp = (Utc::now() + Duration::days(365)).timestamp() as usize;

    let claims = Claims { id, exp };

    let token = jwt::encode(
        &Header::new(Algorithm::HS256),
        &claims,
        &EncodingKey::from_secret(secret.as_bytes()),
    );

    match token {
        Ok(token) => Ok(token),
        Err(e) => Err(AuthenticationError::JwtError(e)),
    }
}
```

Here is the `login` view from frontend,

```
#[function_component(UserLoginView)]
pub fn user_login_view() -> Html {
    let navigator = use_navigator().unwrap();

    let (store, dispatch) = use_store::<AuthStore>();
    let store_clone = store.clone();

    let update_auth_store = Callback::from(move |token: String| {
        console::log!("Updating auth store with token: ", &token);

        dispatch.reduce_mut(|store| {
            store.token = token;

            if !store.token.is_empty() {
                store.is_authenticated = true;
            }
        });

        console::log!("Updated auth store. New token: ", &dispatch.get().token);
    });

    let on_submit_form = Callback::from(move |_data: AccountFormStateData| {
        let update_auth_store_clone = update_auth_store.clone();
        let store_clone = store_clone.clone();

        if !store_clone.username.is_empty()
            && !store_clone.password.is_empty()
            && !store_clone.email.is_empty()
        {
            wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {
                match login_user(LoginUser {
                    username: store_clone.username.clone(),
                    email: store_clone.email.clone(),
                    password: store_clone.password.clone(),
                })
                .await
                {
                    Ok(user) => {
                        let user_token = match user.token {
                            Some(token) => token,
                            None => "Error! Unable to retrieve token".to_string(),
                        };

                        update_auth_store_clone.emit(user_token.clone());
                    }
                    Err(error) => console::error!("API Error: ", error.to_string()),
                };
            });
        }
    });

    if !store.token.is_empty() {
        console::log!("Sucessfully logged in, redirecting to home page..");
        navigator.push(&Route::Home);
    }

    html! {
        <div>
            <AccountForm
                account_form_type={ AccountFormType::LoginAccount }
                form_label={ "Sign In" }
                form_message={ "Don't have an account? " }
                show_form_footer=true
                route={ Route::UserCreate }
                route_label={ "Sign Up" }
                form_submit_button_label={ "Sign In" }
                on_submit={ on_submit_form }
            />
        </div>
    }
}
```

here is the the function that makes request from the frontend to the backend (including the model),

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct LoginUser {
    // pub id: i32,
    pub username: String,
    pub email: String,
    pub password: String,
}

pub async fn login_user(user: LoginUser) -> Result<ResponseUser, Error> {
    let body = serde_json::to_string(&user)?;

    http::Request::post(&format!("{}/users/login", base_url()))
        .header("Content-type", "application/json")
        .body(body)
        .send()
        .await
        .unwrap()
        .json()
        .await
}
```

After filling the form from frontend and sending the request I get this error (from the browser's console),

```
XHR POST http://localhost:8000/users/login

API Error:  invalid type: string "Invalid entry, maybe missing some fields? Req: /users/login", expected struct ResponseUser at line 1 column 61
```

and this error from `Rocket`,

```
POST /users/login application/json:
   >> Matched: (login_user) POST /users/login application/json
   >> Data guard `Json < LoginUser >` failed: Parse("{\"username\":\"Foo6\",\"email\":\"foo6@bar.com\",\"password\":\"foo6bar6\"}", Error("missing field `id`", line: 1, column: 64)).
   >> Outcome: Failure
   >> Responding with registered (unprocessable) 422 catcher.
   >> Response succeeded.
```

Let me know if anything else if needed.

Comment: Presumably `verify_user_credentials()` could return the user's ID, but you haven't shown us the definition of this function. Alternatively, break this down into two parts: fetch user by username, which would return a struct containing information about the user including the user ID and hashed+salted password, then you can verify the password against the hashed password in a second step. I'm assuming this is what `verify_user_credentials()` does internally.

Comment: I have updated the OP with `verify_user_credentials()`.  It does return the user matching username and verify that username's password with the stored hash, but I was asking as in when the user fills the form from the frontend (which has 3 fields, username, password and email) the request needs to send the id of the user along with username, password and email, but I cannot know the `id` without logging in. I think may have just confused my self with something.

Comment: @apoorv569 *the request needs to send the id of the user along with username, password and emai* false, the request **doesn't send the id**, it only sends the username/password. The id is fetched by your **verify_user_credentials** if username/password matches.

Comment: OK, I think I figured it out. on the `match verify_user_credentials` I put `let db_user = ` then change the `encode_token` to take `db_user.id` instead and removed `pub id: i32` from both `LoginUser` models (backend and frontend).  I posted the full function with changes in the OP.

Comment: @cdhowie: would you mind writing down the answer so that the question can be closed as resolved?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution,

First I modified the `login()`

```rust
    pub fn login(conn: &mut PgConnection, user: LoginUser) -> QueryResult<ResponseUser> {
        let db_user =
            match verify_user_credentials(conn, user.username.as_str(), user.password.as_str()) {
                Ok(Some(user)) => user,
                Ok(None) => {
                    return Err(diesel::result::Error::NotFound);
                }
                Err(_) => {
                    return Err(diesel::result::Error::NotFound);
                }
            };

        let secret = env::var("JWT_SECRET").expect("JWT_SECRET must be set.");
        let jwt_token = match encode_token(secret, db_user.id) {
            Ok(token) => token,
            Err(_) => return Err(diesel::result::Error::NotFound),
        };

        let updated_user = diesel::update(users::table.filter(users::username.eq(user.username)))
            .set(users::token.eq(jwt_token))
            .returning(ResponseUser::as_returning())
            .get_result(conn)?;

        Ok(updated_user)
    }
```

then I removed `pub id: i32` from `LoginUser` model (both backend and frontend).

And it works now.